# can multiple people work on one android studio project

Tags: android-studio, android-developer-api

I work with my friend on one android studio project, how can we do sync, work on one project at the same time on different notebooks with OS Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using git or svn integration. 
More about git here:
http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html.

svn:

http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/svn/androidstudio.html